# How to change response http header in get request by spring RestTemplate?

Tags: java, json, spring

I have simple java spring method for creating object

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
Address address = restTemplate.getForObject(url, Address.class);
```

But the server responds me JSON string with wrong *Content-Type:* **text/plain** instead of **application/json** (checked in Postman). And I get the exception:

> Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [class Address] and content type [text/plain;charset=utf-8]

So I think, I need change response header *Content-Type* to right **application/json**, that MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter find out JSON string and run code as well.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

After trying for an hour, I found a short and easy way.

Json converter by default supports only "*application/json*". We just override it to support "*text/plain*".

```
MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();

// support "text/plain"
converter.setSupportedMediaTypes(Arrays.asList(TEXT_PLAIN, APPLICATION_JSON));

RestTemplate template = new RestTemplate();
template.getMessageConverters().add(converter);

// It's ok now
MyResult result = tmp.postForObject("http://url:8080/api", 
            new MyRequest("param value"), MyResult.class);
```

Comment: This is how to deal with dump third-party integrations!

Comment: Not sure but in my case it overrides the MediaType while sending the request also. So the client returns MediaType not supported error

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for help!
In case I can't change response's header. I create new response object with right header.

```
            ClientHttpRequest clientHttpRequest = new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory().createRequest(URI.create(str), org.springframework.http.HttpMethod.GET);
            final ClientHttpResponse clientHttpResponse = clientHttpRequest.execute();
            MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
            Address address = new Address();
            //It always true, because service always returns 200 OK
            if (clientHttpResponse.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.OK) {
                address = (Address) converter.read(address.getClass(), new HttpInputMessage() {
                    public InputStream getBody() throws IOException {
                        return clientHttpResponse.getBody();
                    }

                    public HttpHeaders getHeaders() {
                        HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
                        httpHeaders.putAll(clientHttpResponse.getHeaders());
                        httpHeaders.put("Content-Type", Collections.singletonList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE));
                        return httpHeaders;
                    }
                });
                busStop.setNearestAddress(address.toString());
            }
```

I'm sure it isn't simple and good solution, but It works.

Answer (score 0):

To set the content type for your request you could do something like:

```
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    HttpEntity entity = new HttpEntity(headers);
    ResponseEntity<Address> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET,  entity, Address.class);
    Address address = response.getBody();
```

Comment: No, it doesn't work. It just change headers of request, but not response.

Comment: You can't change the headers for Response, those headers are sent by the server, so, unless you're writing the server's code there is no way to do what you want.

Comment: Check this similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24723394/could-not-extract-response-no-suitable-httpmessageconverter-found-for-response