# Force spring RestTemplate to process plain text as JSON?

Tags: java, json, spring, rest

A web API is responding to a request with `Content-Type:text/plain; charset=utf-8`, but the messageis formatted as if it were a JSON, eg.

```
{
"total": 168,
"page": 0,
"pageCount": 1,
...
}
```

In Spring, this message is processed with a RestTemplate and the JSON is automagically mapped into a `ModelDto` POJO,

```
restTemplate.getForObject(url, ModelDto::class.java)
```

This gives the following error:

> org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [class api.ModelDto] and content type [text/plain;charset=utf-8]

Is there any way to have spring treat this message as if it were a JSON and parse it as such, despite the Content-Type being plaintext?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**UPDATED**

There's no need to create a custom `HttpMessageConverter` since `AbstractHttpMessageConverter` has a method `setSupportedMediaTypes` which can be used to change supported media type:

```
MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
converter.setSupportedMediaTypes(Arrays.asList(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(0, converter);
```

---

I think it's possible via implementing own `HttpMessageConverter<T>`.

`RestTemplate` uses it to convert a raw response to some representation (for instance, POJO). Since it has a list of converters, it finds specific converter for a particular response by its type (e.g `application/json`, etc).

So your implementation of `HttpMessageConverter<T>` should be something like default `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` but with changed supported media type:

```
public class MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter2 extends AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter {

    private String jsonPrefix;

    public MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter2() {
        this(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.json().build());
    }

    public MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter2(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        // here changed media type
        super(objectMapper, MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN);
    }

    public void setJsonPrefix(String jsonPrefix) {
        this.jsonPrefix = jsonPrefix;
    }

    public void setPrefixJson(boolean prefixJson) {
        this.jsonPrefix = (prefixJson ? ")]}', " : null);
    }


    @Override
    protected void writePrefix(JsonGenerator generator, Object object) throws IOException {
        if (this.jsonPrefix != null) {
            generator.writeRaw(this.jsonPrefix);
        }
        String jsonpFunction =
                (object instanceof MappingJacksonValue ? ((MappingJacksonValue) object).getJsonpFunction() : null);
        if (jsonpFunction != null) {
            generator.writeRaw("/**/");
            generator.writeRaw(jsonpFunction + "(");
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void writeSuffix(JsonGenerator generator, Object object) throws IOException {
        String jsonpFunction =
                (object instanceof MappingJacksonValue ? ((MappingJacksonValue) object).getJsonpFunction() : null);
        if (jsonpFunction != null) {
            generator.writeRaw(");");
        }
    }

}
```

Then you can add this to `RestTemplate` object:

```
restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(0, new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter2());
```

Comment: Thanks, let me try this out and will get back

Comment: Looks like another approach is to just change in the inbound header.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42592440/how-to-change-response-http-header-in-get-request-by-spring-resttemplate?rq=1

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: @MykolaYashchenko 
`MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
        converter.setSupportedMediaTypes(Arrays.asList(TEXT_PLAIN, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
        restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(0, converter);` I have added the TEXT_PLAIN in converter still facing the same issue.
`[class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode] and content type [text/plain;charset=ISO-8859-1];`

Comment: @NagendraNigade I guess the reason is that "text/plain;charset=ISO-8859-1" is not the same as "text/plain"

Comment: try to do `converter.setSupportedMediaTypes(Arrays.asList("text/plain;charset=ISO-8859-1", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))`

Comment: @MykolaYashchenko : thanks! your original answer worked!