# Trying to consume content-type [text/json] with Spring Boots's RestTemplate

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, spring-boot

A server is giving me a response in content-type `text/json` and I need to consume it into a Java class. I can do that no problem when the server's response is content-type `application/json`. How can I achieve the same functionality as when I consume an `application/json` content-type when I consume a `text/json` content type using Spring Boot?

I've tried creating an `HttpHeaders` object and then the `setContentType` method but as far as I've seen none of the `MediaType` options will work for `text/json`.

```java
Request req = new Request();
String url = "<url>";

HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType( MediaType.TEXT_JSON ); // this isn't valid but is where I have tried setting the content-type to text/json
HttpEntity< Request > entity = new HttpEntity<>( req, headers );
ResponseEntity< Response > resp = 
    restTemplate.exchange( url, HttpMethod.POST, entity, Response.class );
```

`Request` is the class that determines the servers response and `Response` is the Java representation of the returned json.

Ideally the returned json would be stored into the `Response` class but instead I am getting this error: `InvocationTargetException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner: Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [class Response] and content type [text/json]`

Answer (score 1):

```
MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
converter.setSupportedMediaTypes(Arrays.asList(new MediaType("text","json")));
restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(0, converter);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the converter to the rest template. Please refer [Answer 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49469954/force-spring-resttemplate-to-process-plain-text-as-json) or [Answer 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21355450/spring-resttemplate-with-jackson-as-httpmessageconverter-and-joda-datetime-prope).

```
MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
converter.setSupportedMediaTypes(Arrays.asList(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(0, converter);
```

Comment: I assume that this would work with content-type `text/plain` as in the first [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49469954/force-spring-resttemplate-to-process-plain-text-as-json) you provided by using `MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN`, but I am needing to consume the content-type `text/json`. I'm hoping Spring Boot has the functionality to do so.